# Where does Okun's formula come from?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity

The formula is $(16)$ in Lev B. Okun's paper ["The Concept of Mass"](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.881171).
It gives the force acting on a light body by a heavy spherically
symmetric mass according to general relativity. Unfortunately the author gives no reference, nor does he give any explanation on what the formula means, or if it is an approximation.

I could not find the formula in several books, and an Internet search didn't help me. Here is the formula:

> $${\bf F}_g = \frac{-G_\mathrm{N}M(E/c^2)[{\bf r}(1+\beta^2)-
> \boldsymbol{\beta}({\boldsymbol{\beta}\cdot \bf r})]}{r^3}.\tag{16}$$

Comment: Could it just be a lorentz transformation of the gravitomagnetism "4-potential" (it's not covariant so it's not really a 4 potential I think and we would have to assume  low velocity/gravitational field) for example eq.15 and 16 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0507001 ? But to be sure, you would have to derive the field.

Comment: This seems to be a specialization of [Einstein–Infeld–Hoffmann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Infeld%E2%80%93Hoffmann_equations) for a case when there are only 2 bodies one of which is stationary and much heavier.

Comment: @Syrocco Thank you for your comment. But Okun's formula refers to the
field produced by a stationary mass. He applies it to light deflection
by the Sun. So no gravitomagnetism should be involved.

Comment: @A.V.S. I thought so, but there are important differences from EIH
equation. First, energy of moving particle appears, not mass. Second,
EIH equation as I know it (wikipedia and also "Gravitation") is
approximated to $O(c^{-2})$, so it would work if $\beta\ll1$. Instead
Okun applies it to light or high energy electrons.